# How can I make scroll bar visible on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

On Sublime Text, color of scroll bar is too dark(and little contrast) and it is very hard to find where to drag, especially when color schema is light color like Eiffel.
Is there any way to change color of scroll bar to make it more visible ?

Comment: Check this http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/116003-make-the-scrollbar-markerindicator-more-visible/

Comment: How can I just change the scroll bar color ? And, how can I do in Sublime Text 3, not in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: below answar works for sublime text 2 as well sublime text 3 :)

Answer (score 4):

go to location

```
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Theme - Default
```

or find below file on your packages folder and edit the below file

```
Default.sublime-theme
```

in above file you can search for text ***"normal_thumb_vertical.png"***

add a line "`layer0.tint": [255,80,203]`, below the

`"layer0.texture": "Theme - Default/normal_thumb_vertical.png",` line
example: -

```
{
    "class": "puck_control",
    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Default/normal_thumb_vertical.png",
    "layer0.tint": [255,80,203],
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer0.inner_margin": [0, 10],
    "content_margin": [8, 12],
    "blur": false
},
```

you can edit more scroll properties under  **/** Scrollbars **/** comments, you can apply color code as you want, width etc. you can change

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "under / Scrollbars / comments".